# Comparison of 2 files powershell

Tags: powershell, comparison

I would like to make a comparison of the change date of 2 files and if one of them does not match it resumes the file to another folder and replace it with one that has been modified I know it's only for the modification date of a file is this:

```
$b = Get-ChildItem myfile.txt; $ b.LastWriteTime
```

But I make a comparison it is also that it's this:

```
Compare-Object $ (Get-Content myfile.txt) $ (Get-Content monfichier2.txt)
```

But I can not seem to make it work Please can someone helped me Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Get-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113319) cmdlet to retrieve the `LastWriteTime` property and compare them using `-eq`:

```
if ((get-item myfile.txt).LastWriteTime -eq (get-item monfichier2.txt).LastWriteTime)
{
    # do something
}
```

Use the [Move-Item](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113350) cmdlet to replace the file.

Comment: You may need to compare `.LastWriteTime.Date`, given that the question asks for comparing only the date.

Comment: Good point Joey. `LastWriteTime` also includes the time - `LastWriteTime.Date` doesn`t